# ASP.NET MVC web app - Error 404 when accessing Edit, Details, Delete Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am creating a web application for my database. I have inserted the model and have scaffolded items for each of my tables.

What's weird about this is that my 'Create' works perfectly. However I cannot get the edit, details or delete to work. I just get the error

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

See the example: I have this table:

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDH1g.png)

I have the following code for this page:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication5.Models.SafetyValveData>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Batch_No)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SafetyValvePartNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BAR)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date_Of_Manufacture)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Certificate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Batch_No)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SafetyValvePartNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BAR)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Of_Manufacture)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Certificate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Batch_No }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Batch_No }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Batch_No })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Below is the example of the "Edit" code for this table.

```
@model WebApplication5.Models.SafetyValveData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SafetyValveData</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Batch_No)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SafetyValvePartNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SafetyValvePartNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SafetyValvePartNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BAR, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BAR, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BAR, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_Of_Manufacture, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_Of_Manufacture, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_Of_Manufacture, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Certificate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Certificate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Certificate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**EDIT**

This is the URL it tries to access when editing data from this table:

http://localhost:38636/SafetyValveDatas/Edit/334609%20%20%20%20

Comment: Does the `Batch_No` property is defined as the `string`?

Comment: Hi @Jackdaw, yes the Batch_No is defined as string. Is this an issue?

Comment: You should remove the  leading and trailing whitespaces before saving the values to the database. For example by using [String.Trim Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0). The `%20` in your URL is whitespace code: causing the routing doesn't work correctly, as your expect. _**But better solution to use  `int` type when the property is a number**_.

Comment: Ahh you're right, thank you! Changing this to Int fixed this issue. However, what about the this other table in which the URL is "/CompressorData/Edit/SM13 11 BAR" This is also not working but has no % so does not include white spaces?

Comment: the above "SM13 11 BAR" is stored as varchar

Comment: Add the `Edit` action method declaration for the `CompressorData` controller to the post, please.

Comment: You have to post Edit get and Edit post actions too pls.